# Laravel Category Model Relationships

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have the following table structure in my database.

**Table Name: tiles**

Columns: id, tile_name, tile_thumb, tile_snippet

**Table Name: tags**

Columns: id, tag_title

**Table Name: tile_tags**

Columns: id, tile_id, tag_id

**Models:**
Tile, Tag, TileTag

In my main model class for entries I am specifying the following relationship to a model called TileTag which is a pivot table.

```
<?php namespace Tiles;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tile extends Model {

    protected $table = 'tiles';


   public function tags() {

        return $this->belongsTo('Tiles\TileTag');

    }
}
```

During my foreach loop it returns the tile_name and any other columns from my table, except the ones joined by the relatipnship.

```
@foreach($tiles as $tile)       
        <a href="tile/{{$tile->tile_name}}">
            <li class="col-md-4 mix" data-category="{{ $tile->tags->tag_title }}">
                {!! HTML::image($tile->tile_thumb, null, array('class' => 'img-responsive')) !!}
            </li>
        </a>                
@endforeach
```

How can I get my categories/tags linked to my primary entries when they are sorted during each loop?

I try returning the data during the loop by {{ $tile->tags->tag_title }} but it returns an empty string.

**Controller Method:**

class TileController extends Controller {

```
/**
 * Display a listing of tiles from the database.
 *
 * @return Response
 */

public function index() {

    // Get tile data from the model
    $tiles = \Tiles\Tile::all();

    return view('pages.index', compact('tiles'));

}
```

**Returned Array:**
[image]

Comment: Show controller method that takes care of sending data to the view. You may use `with()` I need to see controller to be sure.

Comment: @Kyslik Hi! I've added the controller method to my post. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you don't have to create a model for Tile_Tag. Laravel can handle ManyToMany relationships out of the box (I suppose that this is the type of the relationship because you use pivot table). Your models should be

```
class Tile extends Model {

protected $table = 'tiles';


 public function tags() {

    return $this->belongsToMany('Tiles\Tag');
 }
}
```

and

```
class Tag extends Model {

protected $table = 'tags';


 public function tiles() {

    return $this->belongsToMany('Tiles\Tile');
 }
}
```

Laravel will know that you have a pivot table named "tag_tile" with columns "tag_id" and "tile_id". Check the relevant documentation [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#relationships)

Then you can iterate through tags collection for each tile like this

```
@foreach ($tiles as $tile)
         {!!$tile->tile_name!!} 
         @foreach ($tile->tag as $tag)
           {!!$tag->tag_title!!} 
         @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Hope it helps.